# keep an absolutely positioned element in viewport (jquery)

Tags: jquery, position, tooltip

I am working on a site now with a lot of tooltips. I want to ensure that the tooltips will always show up fully in the viewport.

I know there are plugins for tooltips, but they won't work for me because the tooltip-ing is done via css (and I can't go change all of them!). Any element that you want to get a tooltip is given a position:relative, and is immediately followed by an element with class='tooltip' - here is the css code:

```
.tooltip{
    display:none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #FEFEE0;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #A6A6A6;
    margin-top:-8px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
*:hover + .tooltip {
    display:block ! important;
}
.tooltip:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

What I would like to do is, every time a tooltip is displayed (or every time the element before the tooltip is hovered), run a function to calculate the offset and make sure it fits in the screen (or move it, if not).

The only thing I can think of now that I didn't try yet is running something like:

```
$("*:hover").each(function(e){
  if ($(this).next().hasClass('tooltip')
    //run some positioning function
}
```

Ok, so I'm no jquery expert and could be that the above is buggy, I didn't try it yet, but you get the idea. But does it make sense? Would it impact performance (in a bad way)?

I've spent hours working on this and coming up empty. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a far more simple solution to your problem. You can use `position:fixed;` to position an element according to the viewport. It will only fail in Internet Explorer 7, as far as I know, so if you care about this, you need to use an IE7 trick to simulate fixed positioning. Also, `*` selectors and what you are doing there will undoubtedly impact on performance.
[This](http://perfectionkills.com/) is a good place to read about CSS and JS profiling. Beware, it is exhaustively detailed, but definitely worth reading.

Comment: i can't change the way the tooltips are working - meaning i can't change the code structure - much of it is loaded dynamically from the database and it would take much too long to get them all. All I can do is change the css code. I don't care about IE7, but I still don't understand how fixed positioning will help - I don't want all tooltips in a certain position, they have to show up near the element that was hovered - so I still need some js to run either way

Answer (score 1):

I examined [tooltipsy plugin](http://tooltipsy.com/) and saw that they are positioning tooltips by the way you mentioned. You can check the samples [here](http://tooltipsy.com/samples.html).

Define a html element type for tooltips and listen their hover event, instead of listening all elements. So you can set title-content datas in each of the elements, rather than creating a tooltip element for all possible data.

```
<a href="#" class="see-tooltip" title="Title-1" content="Content-1">Hover Me!</a>
```

And assign hover event to 'show-tooltip' class.

```
var $tooltip = $('#tooltip'); //select the early created tooltip element here
$('a.show-tooltip').hover(function() {
   var title = $(this).attr('title');
   var content = $(this).attr('content');
   //set title and content to $tooltip here
   //calculate and set positioning here
   $tooltip.show(); //show tooltip after setting it's new position
}, function() {
    $tooltip.hide(); //hide tooltip when hover ends
);
```